# Modifying data within azure mobile services

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I have spent all day trying to find the answer to this but everything I come across does not work for me. I am using azure mobile services and I am trying to update a piece of data that is already in the data base. this documentation located here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library/ gives me the following code to let me modify the entries

```
JObject jo = new JObject();
jo.Add("Id", "37BBF396-11F0-4B39-85C8-B319C729AF6D");
jo.Add("Text", "Hello World");
jo.Add("Complete", false);
var inserted = await table.UpdateAsync(jo);
```

I have implemented this code as ( I have a row of data that has an id of 1234)

```
     public async void updatedata()
    {
        CurrentPlatform.Init();

        JObject jo = new JObject();
        jo.Add("Id", "1234");
        jo.Add("Text", "Hello World");

        var inserted = await client.GetTable<Item>().UpdateAsync(jo);
    }
```

And have my table defined like so

```
    public class Item
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }
```

And then set the information for getting to the mobile service like so
         MobileServiceClient client;
        IMobileServiceTable todoTable;

```
    public void setNumbers()
    {
        CurrentPlatform.Init();


       client = new MobileServiceClient(
    "AppUrl",
    "AppKey"
);
       todoTable = client.GetTable<Item>();

    }
```

after all of this I get a warning on

```
    var inserted = await client.GetTable<Item>().UpdateAsync(jo);
```

that reads "Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Warning CS1701  Assuming assembly reference 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' used by 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile' matches identity 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' of 'Newtonsoft.Json', you may need to supply runtime policy"

when I run it, it throws an Unhandled Exception saying

```
    "System.ArgumentException: The casing of the 'id' property is invalid.

Parameter name: instance
```

how do I fix this? why is it happening? I'm assuming that I am missing something very simple, but have no luck in finding it. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Make all your Property Names in `[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "lower case")]` lower case.

Here:

```
public class Item
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```